# Flash Builder 4 import services .as files

Tags: service, flash-builder

I am working on a shared project in Flash Builder 4. Our data is coming through web services. We have put the generated .as files into vss so that we can share them. What I can't figure out is how to import those files. I see the files that others have created under my services directory but I can't figure out how to get them to appear in my Data/Services view. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this information is in a file with an .fml extension. This is located in your project.model directory. Besides the fact that you can't get to that file from within flash builder to check it out, I don't know that it is a good idea to source control a project file. We are looking at what options we have to help everyone maintain these service files.